# Is there a way to do a complex sum without a new axis in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I need to perform the sum:

```
C_ij = sum_k exp(A_ij*B_k)
```

with numpy, A being a NxN array and B a Nx1 array. Since the product is inside a sum I can't use np.einsum() I think.
For now, I'm doing:

```
C = np.sum(np.exp((np.tensordot(A, B, axes = 0))), axis = 2)
```

But this obliterates my RAM for large arrays since it's creating a NxNxM array even though with np.float16 it's bearable. Nonetheless, is there a way to perform this sum without creating a 3D array?

Comment: write simple python+numpy code (with loops) and use `numba` to optimize it

Comment: How big is N in practice? If it is relatively big (eg. 1000), then using a loop is totally fine. Vectorization is good for small/medium array but it start to be inefficient when the array are huge because filling the RAM is much slower than filling CPU caches. If the computation of a slice takes >2ms, then the overhead of few Numpy function calls (dozens of µs) will be negligible. Alternatively, Numba is indeed a good idea.

Comment: Is `B` (N,1), or (M,) or (M,1).?